# Is it possible to get the number of menu items displayed in the action bar?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm developing an app that uses ActionBarSherlock.

As you know, using `android:showAsAction` attribute, you can display an action menu on action bar. And, the number of menu items displayed on action bar differs according to user's environment(resolution, portrait/landscape and so on).

So, is it possible to get it by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

It varies based on a few factors and it would be safe if you just assume that it varies and can be anywhere from two to five (including a potential overflow menu item).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Hm. I wanted to change the order of action items according to the number of displayed items...

Comment: You should try to use the `groupId` and `ordering` fields for this. The action bar will attempt to keep groups together and order them repsectively.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try menu.size()? I'm not sure what you need exactly.

Answer (score 1):

In my app i am using bottom navigation. I am accessing the menu items by accessing the `size()` property on menu.

for bottom navigation :-

```
bottomNavigation.menu.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking doesn't this do the trick?: `getSupportActionBar().getNavigationItemCount();`

Comment: This is not what I want. This method returns the number of items of tab or list.